# How can I implement an iterative optimization problem in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Assume I have the following two sets of data. I'm attempting to associate products on hand with their rolled up tallies. For a roll up tally you may have products made of multiple categories with a primary and alternative category. In a relational database I would load the second set of data into a temporary table use a stored procedure to iterate through the rollup data and decrement the quantities until until they were zero or I had matched the tallies. I'm trying to implement a solution in Spark/PySpark and I'm not entirely sure where to start. I've attached a possible output solution that I'm trying to achieve though I recognize there are multiple outputs that would work.

```
#Rolled Up Quantities#
owner,category,alternate_category,quantity
ABC,1,4,50
ABC,2,3,25
ABC,3,2,15
ABC,4,1,10

#Actual Stock On Hand#
owner,category,product_id,quantity
ABC,1,123,30
ABC,2,456,20
ABC,3,789,20
ABC,4,012,30

#Possible Solution#
owner,category,product_id,quantity
ABC,1,123,30
ABC,1,012,20
ABC,2,456,20
ABC,2,789,5
ABC,3,789,15
ABC,4,012,10
```

Comment: is the category and product_id 1-to-1 mapping?

Comment: One category can have multiple product_ids but a product_id won't be in multiple categories. At the roll up level one category may be substituted for another.

To hopefully make the categories make more sense imagine that Category 1 is "Chocolate Candy" and Category 4 is "Vanilla Candy". For the first roll-up we want 50 pieces of candy and while we prefer Chocolate we're also ok with Vanilla.

The real data is a lot more complicated so I'm trying to keep it simple enough for an example.

Comment: then how did you get `product_id = 012` for the 2nd row(in possible solution), thought it was from `alternate_category` which based on your description, can have multiple product_ids?

Comment: A product_id can only have one category however when you roll up the quantities your allowed to substitute one product_id for another based on the alternative category.

Comment: for the 2nd row in the list of possible solution:"ABC,1,012,20", I knew from the rollup list, the `ABC,1` has alternate_category=4, from the actual_stock list, `ABC,4` has `012` as product_id. Based on your description, `ABC, 4` might have more than one product_id, if that happens, which product_id should be selected, or the resulting `ABC,1` should have more than two rows (each row corresponding to a distinct product_id and quantity)?  or does each `user+category` have only one product_id?

Comment: In the solution `owner+category+product_id` should be unique.